# How to run generate & migrate in production on a VPS with SQLite database using Drizzle ORM & Remix?

Tags: sqlite, orm, vps, remix.run, drizzle

So I have a database in development that I run `db:generate` & `db:migrate` on to create the database & then run my app that uses that database.

And it works fine.

But how do I do that in production when I can't run direct commands. I'm using https://easypanel.io on a self-hosted VPS.

Do I just use pre-scripts or post-scripts? What is the recommended way to go about it?

```json
    "scripts": {
        "build": "remix build",
        "dev": "remix dev --manual",
        "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
        "prestart": "npm run db:generate",
        "start": "remix-serve ./build/index.js",
        "clean": "rimraf .cache/ build/ public/build/",
        "db:push": "drizzle-kit push:sqlite --config drizzle.config.ts",
        "db:generate": "drizzle-kit generate:sqlite --config drizzle.config.ts",
        "db:studio": "drizzle-kit studio --host localhost --port 3002 --verbose --config drizzle.config.ts",
        "db:seed": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tsx ./app/seed/index.ts",
        "typecheck": "tsc",
        "prettier": "prettier --write app/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
    },
```

I'm thinking of `prestart` like above. What is the best way to do it? I only want it to run one time to create `./sqlite.db` & then don't want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in Next.js using Docker which I had to learn but I bet its similar in Remix. [This is the solution for Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78034830/6141587) but I'll post a Remix one soon as I have another app which uses the same stack but Next.js is replaced with Remix.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misunderstanding what generate does. That's simply generating a migration script which gets created under your /drizzle folder.

Generating a migration script has to be done after you make changes to any of your relations as a part of the development process. Generating a migration script does not do anything to your DB in and of itself.

Also, your remote environment should not be generating migration scripts. You, the developer, create them. Or, more commonly, you tell drizzle to do it automatically based on calculated +/- schema changes. Using that db:generate command.

All the remote environment has to do is run the migration(s), which it will have access to in the code, because you generated it (hopefully) before pushing to remote.

Usually the easiest way to do migrations is to just have the app run them automatically on start. Can also have it run as a script prior to app start up as a part of the code deployment process.

Here's an example of doing it on start: https://github.com/zacharynoble/express-typescript-postgres-drizzle-auth-template/blob/main/src/db/index.ts

Missing robust error handling, but demonstrates the idea ^^

Comment: thanks zack, i got the idea. yeah i did read it before but didnt remember it. i did see the above script in [this blog too](https://www.jacobparis.com/content/remix-drizzle) & modeled it. so if i'm clear, migrations (`db:generate`) are run only in development? no need to run it in production bcz the schema is already created & finalized, right?

Comment: Generate is 'creating' the migration script, migrating is executing the migration script. Generating does not need to be run in prod, but it's not because the schema is already altered somehow, it's because the migration script is already there there to be run the next time your execute a migration. Which I have done historically on app start, but you can do in several ways.

Comment: so in production, which commands do i have to run? because it does give `table does not exist` as the sqlite file is not created during production automatically. locally during development, i do run `pnpm db:generate` to generate migrations & then `db:push` to create the sqlite file. and finally, `db:seed` to add items. what is the production equivalent of this? all i want is to create a database file, create a table. i don't even need to seed in production.